# GZIPStream Compression Always Returns 10 Bytes

Tags: c#, compression, uwp, gzipstream

I'm trying to compress some text in my UWP application. I created this method to make it easier later on:

```
public static byte[] Compress(this string s)
{
    var b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        zipStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        zipStream.Flush(); //Doesn't seem like Close() is available in UWP, so I changed it to Flush(). Is this the problem?
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

But unfortunately this always returns 10 bytes, no matter  what the input text is. Is it because I don't use `.Close()` on the `GZipStream`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are returning the byte data too early. 
The Close() method is replaced by the Dispose() method. So the GZIP stream will be written only when disposed so **after** you leave the `using(GZipStream) {}` block.

```
public static byte[] Compress(string s)
{
    var b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        zipStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        zipStream.Flush(); //Doesn't seem like Close() is available in UWP, so I changed it to Flush(). Is this the problem?
    }

    // we create the data array here once the GZIP stream has been disposed
    var data    = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Dispose();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works like a charm! I tried using `.Dispose()` before, but instead of using it outside the using() block I just called it before returning the data, and that resulted in `ms` getting disposed of as well. Thanks!